# Alterar dados de um List<>

Tags: c#, algoritmo

Olá
Tenho uma coleção assim feito em cima de uma classe:

```
public class Produto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorUnitario { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorTotal { get; set; }
}
```

Partindo do principio quem tenho vários produtos neste list, como faço para alterar a quantidade de um produto especifico?

Comment: `seuList[index].Quantidade = novoValor;`. `index` é a posição do produto que você quer alterar o primeiro é `0`.

Answer (score 6):

Se você souber o índice do elemento que você deseja alterar, pode-se fazer conforme o comentário do @RobertoDeCampos.

```
// Vou preencher somente o Identificador neste exemplo
List<Produto> listaProdutos = new List<Produto>
{
    new Produto { Id = 1 },
    new Produto { Id = 2 },
    new Produto { Id = 3 },
    new Produto { Id = 4 }
};

// Se quisermos alterar a quantidade do elemento que possui identificador igual a 3, basta passarmos o índice dele que é 2.
listaProdutos[2].Quantidade = 10;
```

Caso não saiba o índice e gostaria de efetuar um filtro, pode-se utilizar o `Linq`:

```
// Não se esqueça de adicionar este namespace
using System.Linq;

// Vou preencher somente o Identificador neste exemplo
List<Produto> listaProdutos = new List<Produto>
{
    new Produto { Id = 1 },
    new Produto { Id = 2 },
    new Produto { Id = 3 },
    new Produto { Id = 4 }
};

// Vamos supor que não sabemos o índice, mas gostaríamos de alterar o item com identificador igual a 1.
Produto produto = listaProdutos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == 1);

// Validação para termos certeza que o produto existia na lista e que foi encontrado
if (produto != null)
{
     produto.Descricao = "Produto alterado";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta fazer assim, criar uma lista de produtos

```
List<produto> p = new List<produto>()
{
    new produto { codigo="produto 1",qtd=1},
    new produto { codigo="produto 2",qtd=10}
};
```

Depois acesse pelo seu índice, neste caso está alterando a quantidade da posição 1.

```
   p[0].qtd = 2;
```

Comment: A sua resposta é boa, mas explique o seu código :)

Comment: Wictor Chaves está mais clara a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Hum, questão simples, mas, vamos tentar tornar ela divertida :D

Uma lista genérica geralmente é usada para controlar um grupo de elementos onde não sabemos a quantidade possível desses elementos e assim, não temos como alocar a um array ou outra estrutura (talvez mais eficiente em termos de alocação). Também usamos listas porque elas geralmente são genéricas e nos permitem trabalhar com um classe qualquer que nós criamos.

Além disso, tem o fato de que muitas funções do Framework fornecem suporte a listas, então, elas parecem uma boa pedida.

No entanto, elas são alocadas a medida que você adiciona elementos, então elas referenciam endereços que podem não estar alocados contiguamente em memória, isso gera fragmentação e em máquinas com pouca memória, mesmo com memória livre, você pode provocar um "out of memory" simplesmente por ela estar tão fragmentada que fica impossível alocar um novo elemento nos fragmentos disponíveis.

Estruturas como arrays, são alocados contiguamente, logo, só chamam apis do sistema para alocação de memória, uma unica vez. Então, alocar um array pode vir a ser mais rápido do que alocar uma lista de tamanho regular no longo prazo. Ou então, alocar muitos arrays, pode não ser viável em máquinas com memória muito fragmentada.

Com memória virtual, isso não deveria acontecer, porque o SO vai compensar a falta de memória no disco (que é muito mais lento).

No entanto, na frase, "tenho uma lista", logo surgem dúvidas filosóficas em minha mente, do tipo:

- Vou percorrer linearmente ?
- Essa lista pode aumentar ao ponto de tornar a busca e alteração de um elemento inviável?
- Essa lista é o resultado de um método listar do repositório? Usamos lazy load ?
- Estou tendo cuidado com o antigo limite de 2GB quanto ao tamanho de um objeto ? Eu ja estourei isso.

São tantas perguntas divertidas, mas, voltemos ao tópico, como alterar a quantidade de um produto específico em uma lista?

Bom, pela sua classe, entendo como um produto específico aquele que tiver um valor específico na propriedade ID. Como seu código usa ID como um inteiro, suponto que você não pode ter elementos nulos vindo de outros lugares para comparar com essa propriedade e que o valor 0 não é um ID valido. (deveria?)

Bom, então la vai:

Me parece que o problema real seria, "**Dada uma lista genérica de produtos, como eu procuro e altero um produto específico, de forma eficiente**." Dado fato que você me parece saber usar o operador de atribuição, me parece que seu problema é encontrar eficientemente um elemento em uma lista, dado que nas listas você não tem a ordenação garantida.

Não vou entrar aqui na definição de eficiência, mas, vamos supor cenários relativamente comuns, saindo de uma lista de 5 elementos até uma lista com 1000000 elementos.

Alterei a sua classe por motivos educacionais (e porque eu quero) para ter um construtor simples:

```
public class Produto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorUnitario { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorTotal { get; set; }

    //construtor simples
    public Produto(int ID, string descricao, int quantidade)
    {
        this.Id = ID;
        this.Descricao = descricao;
        this.Quantidade = quantidade;
    }
}
```

Um método auxiliar para montar uma lista com a quantidade que quisermos:

```
    static List<Produto> montaListaProdutos(int quantidadeProdutos)
    {
        //monte uma lista de produtos 

        List<Produto> listaProdutos = new List<Produto>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= quantidadeProdutos; i++)
        {
            Produto p = new Produto( i , "produto " + i.ToString(), i);

            listaProdutos.Add(p);
        }

        return listaProdutos;
    }
```

Primeiro cenário e mais comum: Lista genérica com poucos elementos (5 no meu caso):

R: Não tem muito o que dizer, se a lista é tão pequena, basta percorrer a lista linearmente, comparando a propriedade até encontrar o elemento e depois alterar o que você precisar, exemplo:

```
        //Procure o produto de id 3 e altere a quantidade para 20

        int idprocurado = 3;

        List<Produto> minhaLista = montaListaProdutos(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < minhaLista.Count ; i++)
        {
            if (idprocurado == minhaLista[i].Id)
            {
                minhaLista[i].Quantidade = 20;
            };
        }
```

Neste exemplo, como não sei o lugar onde está o produto de ID 3, eu tenho que percorrer a lista inteira, comparar um a um e se encontrar o produto, eu altero a propriedade. Esse é o cenário mais simples.

Avaliando esse código, primeiro eu sempre percorro toda a lista e testo todos os elementos, encontrando ou não o produto certo, eu gasto sempre 5 iterações do loop para executar o código, ou seja, se a lista tem N elementos, o nosso custo é sempre N, porque eu passo o loop pelos N elementos, quanto menos elementos eu analisar para encontrar, melhor seria o tempo. Não parece bom não é? Mas, como a lista é muito pequena, esse código não seria tão ruim. Na verdade, nem vale a pena perder tempo com uma lista tão pequena.

Uma forma simples de melhorar o código seria adicionar um break para parar de procurar assim que encontrar, você evitaria percorrer toda a lista, o melhor caso seria quando o elemento procurado fosse o primeiro, o pior, quando ele não estiver na lista ou for o ultimo, ai você gastaria 1 loop no melhor e 5 novamente no pior. Em termos de complexidade, dizemos que gastamos O(1) no melhor e O(N) no pior.

Ai vai o código:

```
        int idprocurado = 3;

        List<Produto> minhaLista = montaListaProdutos(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < minhaLista.Count ; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("comparando produto: " + minhaLista[i].Id.ToString());
            if (idprocurado == minhaLista[i].Id)
            {
                minhaLista[i].Quantidade = 20;

                break;
            };
        }
```

Agora vamos a um cenário mais realista, você foi no banco de dados, pegou um lista de 1.000.000 produtos que você não tem ideia dos IDs e está procurando o cara de ID 2500. Você não sabe a ordem dos elementos, nem sabe se o ID 2500 está nessa lista, mas, precisa achar ele, e se encontrar alterar a quantidade para 20.

Você pode até usar o mesmo código, mas, vai ter o mesmo problema porque agora a lista é um pouco maior. Antes de começar o código, vamos ver como eu posso medir e mostrar o resultado das alterações de performance.

Para medir o tempo que eu gasto em um método, eu uso uma classe chamada Stopwatch, do namespace System.Diagnostics, não use o Datetime.Now, porque ele pode fazer consultas de fuso horário e acabar com sua análise, o meu código fica assim:

```
        //Procure o produto de id 3 e altere a quantidade para 20

        int idprocurado = 2500;

        List<Produto> minhaLista = montaListaProdutos(1000000);

        //medindo o tempo
        Stopwatch medidor = new Stopwatch();
        medidor.Start();

        //metodo avaliado
        for (int i = 0; i < minhaLista.Count ; i++)
        {

            if (idprocurado == minhaLista[i].Id)
            {
                minhaLista[i].Quantidade = 20;

                break;
            };
        }

        //final do método, pare de medir o tempo
        medidor.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("tempo gasto em milisegundos: " + medidor.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
```

Veja que para 5 elementos, com o ou sem o break, a diferença de execução é tão pequena que o contador não pegou - mostrou 0 ms - (ao menos na minha máquina). Já com 1.000.000, o contador começa a mostrar alguns ms de tempo de execução, não use Console.WriteLine nos testes de performance, ele consome um tempo razoável.

Só pra você ter idéia, fiz ou outro teste com 5000 elementos, procurando o cara de id 2500, sem o break, o código demorou 0 ms, com o break demorou 0 ms. Mostrando que minha maquina deve ser um foguete ou que a lista é muito pequena pra demonstrar alguma coisa. Já com a lista de 1.000.000 procurando o id 500000, mostrou 24 ms sem o break e 12 ms com o break, provavelmente por que estou inserindo em sequencia e o tempo acaba dobrando porque eu paro de percorrer na metade, mas, lembre que isso é uma particularidade do meu cenário de teste, você não tem garantia de ordenação em listas.

Existem formas de ordenar uma lista genérica, as implicações e a forma de fazer estão neste artigo da Ms:

-> Como implementar ordenação em listas genéricas [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Repare que eu usei um FOR para montar meu loop, eu poderia usar um FOREACH que não teria problema nenhum, usei o for porque facilitou usar a variável I do contador nos exemplos e imprimir na tela. Agora vou usar um foreach para mostrar que ficaria mais limpo e fácil:

```
        //medindo o tempo
        Stopwatch medidorForeach = new Stopwatch();
        medidorForeach.Start();

        //metodo avaliado
        foreach (Produto item in minhaLista)
        {
            if (idprocurado == item.Id)
            {
                item.Quantidade = 20;

                break;
            };
        }

        //final do metodo, pare de medir o tempo
        medidorForeach.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("tempo gasto me milisegundos com o foreach: " + medidor.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
```

O tempo nos dois formatos de loop foi o mesmo, diferença de 1 ms, ou seja, nada mudou, a avaliação da performance ainda é a mesma.

Agora, você também pode usar paralelismo (threads) para percorrer a lista:

```
         //medindo o tempo
        Stopwatch medidorParalelo = new Stopwatch();
        medidorParalelo.Start();

        Parallel.ForEach(minhaLista,
        (item, state) =>
        {
            if (idprocurado == item.Id)
            {
                item.Quantidade = 20;
                state.Break();
            };
        });

        //final do metodo, pare de medir o tempo
        medidorParalelo.Stop();
```

Aqui a alteração de performance foi drástica, o metodo demorou 268 ms, opa, porque ficou pior se eu estou usando várias threads para ler a lista e comparar ao mesmo tempo? Porque paralelismo exige sincronização das threads e escopo próprio de memória, então, "alocar" uma thread não é barato. Só use se você fizer algo pesado durante o loop, como ler uma foto do produto que está num arquivo .jpg do disco.

Opa, então pode ser que essa estrutura de dados que eu estou usando (a lista) não seja uma boa alternativa para a tarefa de buscar e alterar um registro, o que eu uso então?

Antes de mudar estrutura, tente o método Find que recebe um predicado como entrada, ficaria assim:

```
        //medindo o tempo
        Stopwatch medidorFind = new Stopwatch();
        medidorFind.Start();

        //metodo avaliado
        Produto result = minhaLista.Find(x => x.Id == idprocurado);

        result.Quantidade = 20;

        //final do metodo, pare de medir o tempo
        medidorFind.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("tempo gasto me milisegundos com o find: " + medidorFind.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
```

Na minha máquina, o resultado do find ficou 3 ms mais lento que usar diretamente o Foreach ou o For, então recomendo que avalie seus requisitos, de negócio e de performance.

Veja o código no .net Fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/3f6L4C